# Microsoft Graph Excel Upload Issue

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have been able to successfully load a document using the Microsoft graph API. However when I try to open up the excel document in Sharepoint it comes back with an error => (This workbook couldn't be opened because the file format may not be matching with the file extension)

[image: This workbook couldn't be opened because the file format may not be matching with the file extension]

I have implemented this code:

```
    private void UploadFile(string url, string fileName, byte[] data)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken.access_token);

            using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "file");
            request.RequestUri = ConverUrlToUri(url);
            using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
            {
                { new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(data)), "file", fileName }
            };
            request.Content = content;
            request.Content.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            var httpResponse = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                var result = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
        //https://graph.microsoft/com/v1.0/drives/{{DriveID}}/root:/FolderDir/{fileName}:/content
    }
```

I have tried different content-types of ("ContentType", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

("ContentType", "application/octet-stream");

without any luck. Any suggestions would be great.